# Running Standard Notes on self-hosted Standard File Server with Ruby Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to have [Standard Notes](https://app.standardnotes.org/) to run on my self-hosted Ubuntu 16.04 server. I've followed the basic instructions given here on [Github](https://github.com/standardfile/ruby-server), which is to say, install Ruby 2.2+, Rails 5, MySQL 5.6+ database. All done, and running.

After that, in a subdirectory, I pulled the the [Standard File Server git clone](https://github.com/standardfile/ruby-server), set up the `.env` file with this content:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
SECRET_KEY_BASE=use "bundle exec rake secret"
RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_name
DB_USERNAME=db_user
DB_PASSWORD="db_password"

SALT_PSEUDO_NONCE=use "bundle exec rake secret"
```

Initialized the project with:

```
bundle install
bower install
rails db:create db:migrate
```

Again, all fine. When I start the server with `rails s`, this is the output:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:51: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/xml_mini.rb:52: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.0.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:138: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Russell's Teapot
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

I think the two warnings can safely be ignored. The thing that doesn't make sense is that the `.env` file is not read as it's running in dev instead of prod, and on port 3000 instead of 3306. Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

typo at:

```
AILS_ENV=production
```

should be:

```
RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex_A, it actually was a cut-and-paste issue here. The output is still the same.

Comment: Make sure the .env file is in your production server. Because the .env will be ignored by git, since it's in the gitignore file.

Comment: the .env file is in the project directory, together with the git project. Is that the production server? I actually did not define any development or production servers. If you had any info on that, or links, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can add 
      require 'dotenv/load' 
at the top of config/puma.rb file so you can use the dotenv gem in your dev environment
and then run puma to spin up the server instead of rails s

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have opened an issue on Github as well: https://github.com/standardfile/ruby-server/issues/60. Will try the "Deploying a private Standard File server using Docker" version as none of this is working for me.